# How to map to multiple tables from single column using JPA

Tags: java, jpa, entity-relationship

I have 5 tables MainReg, Person, PersonInfo, Company, CompanyInfo

```
CREATE TABLE [MainReg] (
[IdMainReg] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[PersonalObjectId] [int] NULL,
[OwnerId] [nvarchar](36) NULL,
...)

CREATE TABLE [Person] (
[IdPerson] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[PersonInfoId] [nvarchar](36) NULL,
...)

CREATE TABLE [PersonInfo] (
[IdPersonInfo] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
...)

CREATE TABLE [Company] (
[IdCompany] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[CompanyInfoId] [nvarchar] NULL,)
...)

CREATE TABLE [CompanyInfo] (
[IdCompanyInfo] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
...)
```

[MainReg.OwnerId] column references row in table [Company] if [MainReg.PersonalObjectId] = 1 and row in table [Person] if [MainReg.PersonalObjectId] = 2.

My question is, how to map this tables using JPA?

Comment: Take a look at EclipseLink [joined table inheritance](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Inheritance#Joined_Table_Inheritance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to map that in pure JPA. It would need to different foreign keys to be able to map that in JPA: one which would reference Company, and another one which would reference Person.

With Hibernate, you would be able to map that using the [Any](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Any.html) annotation.

Comment: Thank you for a prompt reply. I'm using EclipseLink. I guess I need to look into Hibernate.

Comment: I would rather try to fix your database design.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible. Since I'm working with database that is being used already. I accessing it remotely.

Answer (score 0):

In EclipseLink you can use a @VariableOneToOne relationship to map this.

Otherwise, you may be able to use TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance for it, or change your data model.